# Issue with git push while syncing to remote repo

Tags: git, powershell, cmd, azure-devops

I'm facing a weird issue, with file sync to my remote repo (TFS 2015 Git to VSTS GIT).

I have report 1 being 'sample.txt' which contains 'Hello'. I use these commands in the cmd:

```
git clone 
git remote add vsts PAT 
git checkout master 
git push vsts master
```

It works with no issues, when I modify the file from Hello to Hello 1 -> Perform the same commands and I can see all my changes in remote repo.

Now, I have the same commands in PowerShell where I'm calling

```
if ( $(git remote) -contains 'vsts' )
{
  git remote rm vsts 2>&1|Write-Host
  echo 'VSTS Account removed'
}
git remote add vsts https://Personal%20Access%20Token:TOKEN@my.visualstudio.com/teamproject/_git/repo 2>&1|Write-Host
git checkout ${env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME} 2>&1|Write-Host
git push  vsts ${env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME} -f 2>&1|Write-Host
```

Build succeeds but it won't sync my changes.

Often I see error:

```
Previous HEAD position was eb5c087... Updated test.ps1
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 9 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
Switched to branch 'master'
```

And sometimes, the same commands from will work from the cmd and not from PowerShell.

Comment: Did the answer help you solve the problem? If yes, can you mark the answer? And it will also benefit others who meet similar questions.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is caused by **TFS2015 didn’t update `master` branch with `origin/master` automatically during Get sources step**. So you need to update local `master` branch with `origin/master` branch by adding the command `git reset --hard origin/master`.

And the updated powershell script looks like:

```
if ( $(git remote) -contains 'vsts' )
{
    git remote rm vsts 2>&1|Write-Host
    echo 'VSTS Account removed'
}

git remote add vsts https://Personal%20Access%20Token:TOKEN@my.visualstudio.com/teamproject/_git/repo 2>&1|Write-Host

git checkout ${env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME} 2>&1|Write-Host
git reset --hard origin/master 2>&1|Write-Host
echo 'update local branch with remote successfully'
git push  vsts ${env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME} -f 2>&1|Write-Host
```